# One to Many relationship using breezejs

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I have the following one to many relationship setup between two tables (Case and Recipient)

Case table has one primary key which is identified as an identity (auto-increment) tblRecipient has one primary key which is identified as an identity (auto-increment),and a foreign key relationship with Case.
[image: One To Many]

Case table and related tblRecipient data is pulled:

```
function searchCases(caseID, caseNum)
    {
        var qPredicate;
        if (caseID != '')
        {
            qPredicate = new breeze.Predicate("pkCaseID", "==", parseInt(caseID));
        }
        else if (caseNum != null)
        {
            qPredicate = new breeze.Predicate("CaseNumber", "Contains", caseNum);
        }
        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("case")
            .where(qPredicate)
            .expand("tblRecipients")
        return manager.executeQuery(query);

    }
```

When a button is pressed to add a new recipient, the following code is used to create a new recipient entity:

```
 function createNewRecipient(CaseID)
    {
        var recipientEntityType = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("tblRecipient");
        var newRecipient = manager.createEntity(recipientEntityType, {fkCaseID: CaseID});
        return newRecipient;
    }
```

This code returns this error:
**Error: Cannot attach an object to an EntityManager without first setting its key or setting its entityType 'AutoGeneratedKeyType' property to something other than 'None'**

[image]

*The AutoGeneratedKeyType in the metadata shows None instead of Identity as in the Case table.  We are not sure what we need to change or how to really debug this.  Any help would be appreciated.*

Comment: you mention that the pks are identified as identities. Can you confirm that, in the emdx properties for these 2 PKs, the StoreGeneratedPattern property is set to Identity?

Comment: Thanks for the answer that fixed it.  We originally did not have the PK in the database when first generating the model.  It appears that just updating the model will not set the property.  Either we have to do it manually or remove the table from the model and re-add it.